# Code that runs correctly in FSI doesn't run correctly when project is run

Tags: f#

I am an F# noob and the learning curve has been steep, mostly because of not understanding why things are not working.

Here is some simple code that updates a progress bar that works in FSI (minus the Application.Run line).

```
open System
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Drawing
open System.Threading

let form = new Form(TopMost = true, Visible=true)

let pb = new ProgressBar(Minimum = 0, Maximum = 15, Dock = DockStyle.Fill)
form.Controls.Add(pb)

let threadfunc () =
    Thread.Sleep(5000)
    for i = 0 to 15 do
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        pb.Invoke(Action(fun _ -> pb.Value <- i)) |> ignore

let thread = new Thread(threadfunc)
thread.Start()

[<STAThread>]
do Application.Run(form)
```

This same code drawws a window with a progress bar that doesn't update and then crashes when I try to build the project and run it from the debugger.

Comment: This runs fine when I build it, but it crashes on exit, because the ProgressBar is accessed after it is disposed.

Comment: On my system the progress bar updates fine from FSI. From VS10 the progress bar never udpates, or it turns blue.

Comment: FWIW, I found WPF to be a lot better than WinForms for this kind of reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this works, but try adding `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` before you create your form.